# Question page opens, then immediately returns to question list

Tags: bug, mobile-web, google-chrome

The last two days, using Chrome on Android, I've been having sporadic problems navigating to questions from the question list. The question page opens and then the page immediately returns to the list.

I haven't noticed similar problems on other sites, so it doesn't feel like anything is wrong with the browser.

Browser v57.0.2987.132

Update - still a big problem, and seems to happen most on clicks in the hot topics list.

Comment: Browser version?

Comment: @LuisAlberto -- I'll update when I'm near the device again.

Comment: @LuisAlberto  v57.0.2987.132

Comment: And if you browse the full site theme? Still having this problem?

Comment: Also, do you have SE android app installed on your device?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, have the app, don't care for it.  I'll set the "request desktop site" flag, and see what happens, if that's what full theme means.